# Historical data on buy-sell recommendations by stock market analysts

Tags: data-request, economics, finance

Investments banks issue buy-sell recommendations based on their equity research. An [example of Goldman Sachs' for Apple](http://pdf.cyberpresse.ca/lapresse/dufour/AAPLBUY.pdf).

Is there a structured dataset that contains key parameters of such recommendations issued by banks: recommended positions, suggested return potential, or others?

Or maybe a website where this information can be extracted from?